# Can I use .ready() for other than document elements of DOM?

Tags: jquery

Is [ready()](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) for [document](http://www.w3schools.com/dom/dom_document.asp) only or i can use that function for other elements. Example below:

```
jQuery('.myclass').ready(function(){ alert('ready'); })
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, although I would recommend using `.load()`

```
$('#element').load(function() {
   //do stuff!
});
```

Answer (score 0):

load() dont work in all elements, it is solely for img, iframe, document etc. ready() do work but inside function are failing